# Getting file size of a random file in SAS (Windows)

Tags: sas

I know that the finfo function in SAS returns filesize as one of the info fields in Unix. Is there an equivalent in Windows?

I need to be able to get the total disk space used in a particular folder from within SAS/AF code. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks,

-- A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've previously posted a sas macro to read windows directory listing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409543/using-sas-macro-to-pipe-a-list-of-filenames-from-a-windows-directory/1423573#1423573).

Comment: That was very helpful. I got it to work great with some tweaks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have **SAS version 9.2 or later** then this link will work regardless of OS:

http://support.sas.com/kb/38/267.html

Here is a paraphrased version of the link answering your question exactly:

```
%let filename = d:\sasdev\autoexec.sas;
data info; 
  length filesize $60; 
  drop rc fid close; 
  rc=filename("myfile","&filename"); 
  fid=fopen("myfile"); 
  filesize=finfo(fid,"File Size (bytes)"); 
  close=fclose(fid); 
  put filesize=;
run;
```

Cheers
Rob

PS - Have you checked out [www.runsubmit.com](http://www.runsubmit.com)?  It's just like StackOverflow but for SAS related questions only.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately we still have to support SAS 9.1.3 so any 9.2 specific features become unusable. But I can definitely do some version-specific stuff in my methods just as I'm doing OS specific things right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do something crufty and write a utility function that does the following:

- If the file is a SAS dataset, then use standard SAS functions to get the filesize (some lrecl and nobs math)
- Otherwise, if it is UNIX or SAS 9.2, use finfo
- Otherwise, use a modified version of the macro written by @rkoopmann

Note that this is ok for me only because my requirements are to be able to get the size of a particular file.