# Adding common data to multiple text files

Tags: sas, copy-paste, notepad

The basic trouble is in adding some common data to multiple text files. The output of a SAS program i wrote is many text files in a folder like 30 to 50 text files, now i have to add a mobile number at the top in each file. Right now i do this by manually copying the number and then opening the text files and then pasting the number. Can someone suggest me an alternative way to do this maybe a SAS program or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This program will add the first record to your file (there is no way to 'insert' a new record at the start, the file has to be rebuilt):

```
%let myfile=C:\temp\MyFile1.sas;
data _null_;
infile "&myfile" ; /* consider using lrecl option if wider than 256 chars */
file "&myfile.";
input; 
if _n_ = 1 then put 'Some Phone Number'; 
put _infile_; 
run;
```

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409543/using-sas-macro-to-pipe-a-list-of-filenames-from-a-windows-directory/1423573#1423573) for how to get a list of the text files in your folder..

Comment: This is the error i am receiving
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference MYFILE not resolved

Comment: You need to run the first line - "%let myfile=xxx;", and replace xxx with the full path and name of your file.  The &myfile variable could then be parametererised in a macro, to loop through your list of files..

Comment: Still unable to get the result i mean the number is not being added to the file ...though the code is running if you dont mind could you plz explain me the role of data _null_; and if _n_=1  in the code.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: data _null_;
file "path and name of the file";
put "99999999";
run;

I wrote this and it worked ....once again thanks for your help it would be great if you can still explain me the meaning of the lines i asked above.

Comment: data _ null _ means we don't create an output dataset (no need, we're using file statement to output a text file instead).  _ n _ = 1 tells the data step that we only want to execute the put statement for the FIRST record essentially..  (it's an internal incrementer)